# Flutter Image Picker not working due to plugins not automatically attaching to activity

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, imagepicker

I have added flutter in an existing Android app and I have been facing issues with Image picker library not working, showing the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker_android)
```

According to the error I understand that it's due to GeneratedPluginRegistrant not being registered and I have to override `configureFlutterEngine` method. As I need to open the flutter module inside a fragment I cannot extend my activity using `FlutterActivity` because it does not support `getSupportFragmentManager`.
I tried extending my activity using `FlutterFragmentActivity` and was able to override `configureFlutterEngine` method but then faced the following error.

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x245a3c5c (unknown) for fragment FlutterFragment{647abea (0b17a247-4e8e-42bc-b5f3-6ab0796e458b) id=0x245a3c5c flutter_fragment}
```

Following are my MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mch.testplugin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context mContext;
FlutterFragment flutterFragment;
private static final String TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT = "flutter_fragment";
FlutterEngine mFlutterEngine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flutterFragment = (FlutterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT);

            // Create and attach a FlutterFragment if one does not exist.
            if (flutterFragment == null) {
                flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.createDefault();

                flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withNewEngine()
                        .initialRoute("/")
                        .build();

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(
                                R.id.frame_layout,
                                flutterFragment,
                                TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT
                        )
                        .commit();


            }
    });

}


//    @Override
//    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
////        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
//        mFlutterEngine = flutterEngine;
//        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new FlutterEngine(this));
//    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>'
```

Can someone please guide me the right way to do this? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for similar problems is simply to stop the app and press the run button again